# WARNING: <module> is not a valid modulename on sys.path

Tags: python, ipython, python-module

I have the following structure:

```
my_program/
    main.py
    packages/
        __init.py__
        my_package/
           __init__.py
            foo.py
        my_other_package/
           __init__.py
            my_other_module.py
```

In IPython, when I cd into `my_program/packages/my_package` and I type:

```
run -m foo.py
```

I get the warning:

```
WARNING: u'foo.py'is not a valid modulename on sys.path
```

My question is why?

Looking at the [execution.py](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/magics/execution.py) IPython magic I see:

```
if "m" in opts:
            modulename = opts["m"][0]
            modpath = find_mod(modulename)
            if modpath is None:
                warn('%r is not a valid modulename on sys.path'%modulename)
                return
            arg_lst = [modpath] + arg_lst
```

but I am not sure I understand why they have that if statement for when `modpath` is `None`.

[Here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/api/generated/IPython.utils.module_paths.html) is the spec of `find_mod`:

[image]

### Update:

If I try `run -m foo` (i.e I drop the `.py` extension) I get the following instead:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

The error happens in this line in `foo.py`:

```
from ..my_other_package import my_other_module
```

Answer (score 0):

just from playing, try to do `run -m foo`